# Is the gettimeofday function thread safe in Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux

The current time must be stored globally in order for gettimeofday to work, however I am not sure if the function modifies any global state so that concurrent execution is undefined.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

gettimeofday is thread safe.

The (posix) functions listed [here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_09.html#tag_02_09_01) might not be, gettimeofday is not one of them.

Comment: +1 for citation instead of just "it's safe because it shouldn't need to do anything unsafe..."

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is thread-safe.  The only data it modifies is in the structures you pass pointers to, so an implementation that wasn't thread-safe would have to be doing something spooky.

Best of luck on your project.

Answer (score 2):

In `glibc` the [`gettimeofday(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) is a simple wrapper around a system call (it's a [`vsyscall`](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-4.html#ss4.6) actually). No data is touched in the userland. It is thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

No data is modified with this call. You just get a copy. Hence its completely thread safe.